# How to exclude Google Tag Manager hits from a Google Analytics View?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

it may sound stupid that we need to implement UA-3 just before it's sunset, but I have a requirement where I need to migrate from the in-line UA-3 code to GTM-based UA-3 tracking. The process I have chalked out is:

1. Suppose I have a view 'UA-old'. Now, I'd create a new view in my UA property, say 'UA-new'. Now I implement GTM code to collect UA-3 hits from the website
2. Filter-Include only hits from GTM source into 'UA-new'
3. Filter- Exclude all hits from GTM in 'UA-old'
4. Compare and monitor the traffic in both
5. When the result is satisfactory, remove UA in-line code from website, and remove GTM hit exclusion filter from UA-old
6. Delete UA-new

Now, I am getting stuck at point 2 & 3. How do I exclude or include GTM hits from a view?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Due to how limited and bugged GA4 still is, UA accounts still may make complete sense to use in short-term.

In your case, you probably don't want to mix the data from GTM and GA4 in the same property. It may be better to have different properties for data comparison. Just to avoid merging user and session counters in one property and then shared in views. This can be achieved by defining a different property id in GTM. You may need to also define the tracker name in gtm just to make sure the settings are kept separately from your front-end tracker.

Still, you can do it the way you want with a bit of tinkering. The problem is that there's no obvious indication in the analytics hits between, so you will have to "mark" your events in GTM. Say by setting a certain custom dimension to something. Then you'll be able to filter by this custom dimension's values.